# Java 1.6 to support Sending notifications payload to Apple’s new HTTP/2 spec

Tags: apple-push-notifications, http2, java-6, javapns

Would like to know if Sending remote notification payload to Apple’s new HTTP/2 API service can be supported with Java 1.6. If yes, how to support the same?

Thanks